# Correct resource naming

Tags: rest, microservices

I have an API with some microservices, Users, Bets, Games...

Most of the endpoints follow this pattern:

```
server:8080/users
server:8080/users/{id}
server:8080/users?name=[]
```

They're mapped in a load balancer so when a url with the path /users is requested it goes to users service.

I need to add stats for users and bets services. Doing this:
`server:8080/users/stats`, is completely wrong. I think that I should treat stats as a resource itself, but in that case I should start putting a lot of rules in the load balancer eg:

If the incoming url is:

```
server:8080/stats?type=users
```

I feel that is not right to route from the load balancer depending of query params. Do I have a completely wrong approach on this? Any guidance on this would be really helpful.

Comment: Any spelling you want to use is fine.  You may need to prioritize your constraints, and choose a spelling that satisfies the most important ones.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of miroservices:
Option 1:
Create a new stats microservice, if you feel is not directly related to users, makes sense to separate concerns.
Option 2:
users.api.yourcompany.com/-> Users service
stats.api.yourcompany.com/-> Users service

Comment: But each service has it's own database, Users and Bets. Would it be correct that the new service access multiple databases?
Also, creating a new service for a new resource sounds like a lot, there will be only two endpoints with a few queries.

Comment: then it sounds like it's correct that the stats are under /users , if the logic depends on the users data in that database